# How to delete not fully uploaded file on server when client abort the ajax file upload or it gets aborted by a network connection error

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, server, upload

Suppose, a user is uploading a file (10 MB) through ajax and the user aborts the uploading in the middle (5 MB) by clicking a button. But the file (5 MB) is still on the server.

How to delete the file (5 MB) on the server when the user aborts the uploading or it gets aborted by a network connection error. Or there is any way to know that the user aborted the upload and file should not be written on server?

Comment: Either immediately with something like `.on("abort", deleteFile)` or periodically with a cron job or something (wipe all files older than one hour, for instance)

Comment: What if there is a network connection error that aborts the file uploading.